# Deducing the number of divisors if we know their form

Tags: combinations, inclusion-exclusion

The task is to find out how many positive integers divide at least one of the given numbers: 
$10^{60}$, $20^{50}$, $30^{40}$. This is easily calculated using the inclusion-exclusion principle.

First, we have to figure out the form of divisors for each of these numbers.

- $10^{60}=(2\cdot5)^{60}=2^{60}\cdot5^{60}$, which means divisors of
  this number are of form $2^{i}\cdot5^{j}$ where $0\le{i},j\le{60}$
- $20^{50}=(2\cdot2\cdot5)^{50}=2^{2\cdot50}\cdot5^{50}$, divisors:
  $2^{2\cdot{i}}\cdot5^{j}$ where $0\le{i},j\le{50}$
- $30^{40}=(2\cdot3\cdot5)^{40}=2^{40}\cdot3^{40}\cdot5^{40}$,
  divisors: $2^{i}\cdot3^{j}\cdot5^{k}$ where
  $0\le{i},{j},{k}\le{40}$

Number of divisiors of form $2^{i}\cdot5^{j}$ where $0\le{i},j\le{60}$ equals $61\cdot61$, because we have 61 combinations for both $i$ and $j$. Following this logic, number of divisiors of form $2^{2\cdot{i}}\cdot5^{j}$ where $0\le{i},j\le{50}$ should be $51\cdot51$, because we have 51 choices for $i$ and $j$. **But**, the solution I read said the number of these divisors is $101\cdot51$. I feel like this has something to do with $2^{2\cdot{i}}$, although this equals to $4^{i}$ and shouldn't change anything. Could the solution be wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should just express $20^{50}$ as $2^{100}\cdot5^{50}$

Comment: Why do you say a divisor of $20^{50}$ has to be of the form $2^{2\cdot i}\cdot5^j$? Isn't $2$ a divisor of $20^{50}$? How is $2$ of that form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $2^{2*50}=2^{100}$. Thus, there are $101$ such numbers of the form $2^j$ such that $0 \leq j \leq 100$. You reasoned about this the right way but got a little too caught up! The first and last problems behave similarly since their exponents were such that $i=j=k$.

Just to complete the problem: Using the reasoning you mentioned, we have that there are $101*51$ ways to make numbers of the form $2^j5^k$ such that $0\leq j \leq 100$ and $0 \leq k \leq 50$.